# How to move a an image to the right of title text in the head of my form

Tags: css, asp.net

What CSS Code would I use to get an image to the right of my titletext? Currently it's in the center of the page and a little bit below, and it looks gross!

This is what I have right now:

```
<body>
   <form runat="server">
   <div class="page">
   <div class="header">
   <div class="title">
      <h1>
         Text
      </h1>
   </div>
   <div class="loginDisplay">
   <div class="irc_mutc" style="height: 99px; width: 670px">
      <div id="irc_mimg" style="">
         </a>
         <img id="irc_mi" height="84" class="floatright" 
            src="imagewebsite.com" 
            style="margin-top: 0px;" width="459" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please improve the code sample. The HTML is invalid (for example the `</a>` and the formatting is off. Also show us your CSS that contains what you already tried to get it going.

Comment: include current screenshot and expected output?

Comment: There appears to be a rogue closing anchor tag in your HTML?

Comment: RIght now I'm trying to change my background image to lightgreen. After I put my closing tag </h1> I put <link rel="stylesheet" href="TextFile.css"> with a related file TextFile.css which contains the following:

Comment: <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #d8da3d }
  </style>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want ... but from what I understand :

```css
.header h1,
.header img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12px;
}
//Clearfix
.header img::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Text</h1>
    <img id="irc_mi" src="//lorempicsum.com/futurama/459/84/2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.floatright { float:right; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
     <img id="irc_mi" height="84" class="floatright" src="http://placehold.it/459x84" style="margin-top: 0px;" width="459" />
            <h1>Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <div class="irc_mutc" style="height: 99px; width: 670px">
                <div id="irc_mimg" style="">
                    <!--img id="irc_mi" height="84" class="floatright" src="http://placehold.it/400x200" style="margin-top: 0px;" width="459" />-->
  </div>
            </div>
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not clear exactly what you're after here but this will give you an image aligned to the right of your header.

```css
<style>
.floatright { float:right; }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
     <img id="irc_mi" height="84" class="floatright" src="http://placehold.it/459x84" style="margin-top: 0px;" width="459" />
            <h1>Text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <div class="irc_mutc" style="height: 99px; width: 670px">
                <div id="irc_mimg" style="">
                    <!--img id="irc_mi" height="84" class="floatright" src="http://placehold.it/400x200" style="margin-top: 0px;" width="459" />-->
  </div>
            </div>
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add the CSS within the head tag. I have updated my answer accordingly, however I would recommend using an external stylesheet.